# Как сделать чтоб заходить под 1 аккаунтом linux на "шары" винды

Tags: windows, ubuntu, сервер, samba

Есть парк компов 98шт, сервак на базе ubuntu server 14.04, на нем расшаренные папки, раньше с виндовыми компами проблем не было, так как на шаре не было  пароля, но с появлением обновления 1709 (на вин10) запрещается заходить на расшаренные папки без пароля, и вот тут начинается гемор, вернул обратно парольный вход, создал юзера для входа на шару, с одного виндового компа зашел под этим юзером, все норм, с другого захожу и выходит ошибка мол нельзя заходить под одним пользователем на несколько компов, в итоге получается надо делать 90 с лишним учеток для каждого пользователя? или можно обойтись малой кровью? Подскажите

Comment: прикрутить какой-нибудь ldap?

Comment: Тока что зашёл на анонимную `ro` самбашару со свежей win10. И на `rw` для всех. УМВР.

Answer (score 0):

Я просто в локальных политиках безопасности на винде разрешил беспарольный доступ

Comment: Это решение, конечно, но, максимум, домашнее.

Comment: Да, домашнее. Но если 98 компов, то, по идее есть домен. А если есть домен, то ввести туда линуксовый сервак и авторизоваться по доменным учеткам